# Does logging in with username & password still work with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, token

When i try to find any resource to log with a username and password (instead of a token), all of them fail. Is this still possible?

Comment: No, you can’t. You also can’t log in to a user account with a token since discord.py 1.7+

Answer (score 1):

As **Łukasz Kwieciński** pointed out, it's not possible using discord.py with any version above 1.7.

On older versions you can use a user token and pass `bot=False` as an argument of client.run

This however is explicitly forbidden by the terms of service of discord and will result in ban for the user, the bot, and whomever else involved with the selfbot.